# What is the solution to the "406 Not Acceptable" problem?

Tags: php, apache, api, cpanel

i have error #406 Not Acceptable

just when i add "url" http:// on end api url like this:

http://sl.abudayah.com/api.php?create=http://

how can me fix it ?

What is the solution to the "406 Not Acceptable" problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to encode the parameter being passed.  If you're using PHP to generate your URLs, go with [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode):

```
$url .= 'create=' . rawurlencode('http://'); // or however you get the appropriate string
```

If your link is being generated in another language or by hand, you'll need to look up the appropriate means of encoding it.  It all depends on what you want, really...

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to consult the documentation for your api, and find out what is acceptable.

Comment: thank you.. everythink is acceptable but url is not acceptable see this: http://sl.abudayah.com/api.php?create=http:// (not acceptable)......... http://sl.abudayah.com/api.php?create=helloworld (acceptable)